# Custom buttons in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

How can I create buttons like this in silverlight. Do I need expression blend for this.

Since I need to use the modified buttons at many places in my application, should I do it as a user control?

[image]

Comment: Do you just have the look or do you have the gradient color detail already?  Blend will help a lot if you're just going by look ... however it is totally doable with just working with the xaml in a style (can be time consuming though).  You'll want to view the xaml and designer at the same time until you get the gradients looking how you want them.  Then you can create your own inherited version of the button or just use the style on individual buttons or all buttons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need a `UserControl` for this, just a custom `Button` template as a style resource, which then you can reuse by setting the style on any `Button` instance.

While it's doable without Blend, I highly recommend you at least get the trial, it's a really really nice IDE for design / visual development!

Edit: As a little present here's a starting point :)

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                      <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                      <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                           <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.4" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                      </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                          <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                  <Border.Background>
                                      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                          <GradientStop Color="#FF707070" Offset="0"/>
                                          <GradientStop Color="#FF666666" Offset="0.49"/>
                                          <GradientStop Color="#FF5e5e5e" Offset="0.51"/>
                                          <GradientStop Color="#FF535353" Offset="1"/>
                                      </LinearGradientBrush>
                                  </Border.Background>
                          </Border>
                          <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                      <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="2" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.Effect>
                          </ContentPresenter>
                          <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0"/>
                          <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    </Grid>
              </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Should the template ButtonStyle1 be placed in App.xaml. How should I reference it from my xaml page. I tried to do as per the guidelines given in some sites but did not work.

Comment: Easiest is to create an `<Application.Resources>` tag and a `<ResourceDictionary>` tag inside `App.xaml` and paste it there, but you can also create a separate XAML to be your `ResourceDictionary` and import that into your `App.xaml` using `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>`

Comment: I am trying to add mouse over effects over your template. Should I create a new XAML with this code in Expression Blend for that so that the Events like mouse over, disabled etc are visible.

Comment: Well in my example `MouseOver` and `Pressed` states are not implemented to keep it simple, so what you can do is to change the colour of the `Background` using the state recording feature in Blend (when editing the template click on any state and the properties you change then will be saved as animation not touching the base state) or if you want to do something more advanced just add more elements like `Rectangles`, see how `Focus` or `Disabled` states work!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without Blend by hand, but believe me, using Blend will give you a lot more power and you'll get more amazing results in the fraction of time you would need if you decided to do it all by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely recommend Blend as it saves so much time when styling controls and creating templates.

However, if you're not set on having the buttons *exactly* the same as the image, there are several themes that you could use (such as [JetPack](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/themes/jetpack.html)) from which you could borrow the templates and amend the colours relatively easily in XAML.